# how to get debug logs of application which is distributed though Airwatch MDM solution

Tags: android, mdm, airwatch

We have distributed an application to a customer but the application is not working on their devices. We need to identify the issue using debug logs from the application. We have previously used Test Fairy and were able to get the logs from user's devices. Now we are using the Airwatch MDM solution and want the log from user's device.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you've embedded the AirWatch SDK into your application and are leveraging AirWatch to actively pull those logs back I don't believe you will be able to access them.

Alternatively I would recommend embedding Crashlytics into your app solution. It will report back the crash stack, usage statistics and any other custom logging you wish to send back upstream to their server. I only recently started using their product, which is free, and it has proven to be invaluable for debug resolution.